# method declared as public not found

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

In my common.cs class I have the below declarations for a list based on a class:

```
public static List<edbService> edb_service;

public class edbService
{
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDescr { get; set; }
    public string ServiceInterval { get; set; }
    public string ServiceStatus { get; set; }
    public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
    public string SourceApplication { get; set; }
    public string DestinationApplication { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string credentials { get; set; }
    public string orgid { get; set; }
    public string orgunit { get; set; }
    public string customerid { get; set; }
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
}
```

I have a public method to populate the list from xml data files declared like this in the same class (common.cs):

```
#region PublicMethods

public List<edbService> populateEDBService(string xmlDataFile)
{
try
{
XElement x = XElement.Load(global::EvryCardManagement.Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + xmlDataFile);

// Get global settings
IEnumerable<XElement> services = from el in x.Descendants("Service")
         select el;
if (services != null)
{
  edb_service = new List<edbService>();
  foreach (XElement srv in services)
  {
  edbService edbSrv = new edbService();

  edbSrv.ServiceID = srv.Element("ServiceID").Value;
  edbSrv.ServiceName = srv.Element("ServiceName").Value;
  edbSrv.ServiceDescr = srv.Element("ServiceDescr").Value;
  edbSrv.ServiceInterval = srv.Element("ServiceInterval").Value;
  edbSrv.ServiceStatus = srv.Element("ServiceStatus").Value;
  edbSrv.ServiceUrl = srv.Element("ServiceUrl").Value;

  foreach (XElement ServiceHeader in srv.Elements("ServiceHeader"))
  {
    edbSrv.SourceApplication = ServiceHeader.Element("SourceApplication").Value;
    edbSrv.DestinationApplication = ServiceHeader.Element("DestinationApplication").Value;
    edbSrv.Function = ServiceHeader.Element("Function").Value;
    edbSrv.Version = ServiceHeader.Element("Version").Value;

    foreach (XElement ClientContext in ServiceHeader.Elements("ClientContext"))
    {
    edbSrv.userid = ClientContext.Element("userid").Value;
    edbSrv.credentials = ClientContext.Element("credentials").Value;
    edbSrv.orgid = ClientContext.Element("orgid").Value;
    edbSrv.orgunit = ClientContext.Element("orgunit").Value;
    edbSrv.customerid = ClientContext.Element("customerid").Value;
    edbSrv.channel = ClientContext.Element("channel").Value;
        edbSrv.ip = ClientContext.Element("ip").Value;
        }
      }

      edb_service.Add(edbSrv);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  /* Write to log */
  Common.logBuilder("CustomerCreate : Form --> CustomerCreate <--", "Exception", Common.ActiveMQ,
    ex.Message, "Exception");
  /* Send email to support */
  emailer.exceptionEmail(ex);
  }
  return edb_service;
}
```

but the problem is, in my calling class when I try to have a list returned from this method, it is not found - I get a compile error that an object reference is required.

I am trying to call it like this:

> Common.edbService edb_service = Common.populateEDBService("CardUpdate.xml");

and I get the below error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'EvryCardManagement.Common.populateEDBService(string)'

What am I doing wrong?

I would like to have a generic method that can be called from several classes (which run async after being instantiated by background workers on my form)

Comment: Show how you are trying to call the function.

Comment: Probably it has to do with the fact that the `edbService` is internal, while you're trying to return a collection of that internal class. Hence why I assume that's the problem. Try making the `edbService` class public, just to see if the error still occurs.

Comment: I have edited to give more detail - also, it is now Public, and still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making your method as static.

```
public static List<edbService> populateEDBService(string xmlDataFile)
{
   //Your code here
   ....
}
```

Now you can call this method from all the other classes by using `common.populateEDBService();`

Comment: I made the method static, and tried: `Common.edbService edb_service = Common.populateEDBService("CardUpdate.xml");` but now get the error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EvryCardManagement.Common.edbService>' to 'EvryCardManagement.Common.edbService'**

Comment: Its obvious, your method returns a list, you should assign the value to a list, not to a single object

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello: it compiles with `List<Common.edbService> edbService = Common.populateEDBService("CardUpdate.xml");` so thanks!

Comment: It should be something like this: List<edbService> yourListName = Common.populateEDBService("CardUpdate.xml"); Please mark the answer in case it works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need either to create the class `static`, or to create an object to call it.

```
class edbService { }

public static void Main() {
  //this is error
  edbService.populateEDBService("");

  //this is correct
  edbService s = new edbService();
  s.populateEDBService("");
}
```

The last line in my example shows the object reference required by the compiler. The `s` variable here is the object reference.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any missing values in your XML? The`.Value` property won't work if the value is missing. So if ServiceID is missing then `srv.Element("ServiceID").Value;` will cause an error. You can get it to return an empty string for missing values, for example, by instead using `(string)srv.Element("ServiceID");`

Comment: some can be missing but these are handled, thanks for the suggestion tho